# Log4Net is not working with Sql Server 2005

Tags: asp.net-2.0, log4net

I want to make Log4Net to enter logs in MS Sql Server 2005. I am using .NET 2.0.
Here is the code till now I have written:

Web.Config File

```
<configSections>
  <section  name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings/>
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=XYZ;Initial Catalog=ACC;Integrated Security=True" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>

</log4net>
```

Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

}
```

Page_load

```
try
{
    // There is no such Session, this is just to create error
    if (Session["userName"].ToString() == "Admin")
    {

    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    log4net.ILog log =log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType); 
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();  
    log.Debug("log Debug",ex);  
    log.Info("log Info",ex);  
    log.Warn("log Warn",ex);  
    log.Error("log Error",ex);  
    log.Fatal("log Fatal",ex);           
}
```

Actually I have tried it by storing lod details in Log folder in my directory, which was working fine. But I want to store information in Sql Server 2005.

Am I missing something? or I have to correct some where.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I Think the code of the webconfig is represented here. Please check this URL to know the web.config setting and stored procedure that I have used

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I made some mistake when I edited your question, then the problem is that you do not reference the appender like this:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />    
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

Some further comments:

- You do not need to call the `Configure` method twice
- You do not need an exception to test logging

Comment: In general cases we use to put the login User Name or role into the database too. How can I do it? I have modified stored procedure, Now my table has one more column i.e. UserName. How can I provide userName to the database ?

Comment: yes, after the appender. for the username you need to configure an additional parameter and do what is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007612/track-user-with-log4net-for-a-website/3009077#3009077. but I really recommend that you read that tutorial (that I posted in your last question) first. It is important to understand a few key concepts before you use log4net. In the end you will save time if you read it before just trying out something.

Comment: Thanks for your help and valuable advice. I am now going to read some tutorials. Thanks again